# Make call with alternate provider if NOANSWER

Tags: asterisk

I have two voip providers, one free an the other paid. The free provider only allows local calls to certain area codes, so I need to fall back to the the paid provider if a call fails. 
At the moment, I have the following context in my `extensions.conf` file:

```
[globals]
; freephoneline.ca
PRIMARY_PROVIDER=fpl
; voip.ms
SECONDARY_PROVIDER=voipms

[local]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=${OUTGOING_NAME})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@${PRIMARY_PROVIDER})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${OUTGOING_NUMBER})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/1${EXTEN}@${SECONDARY_PROVIDER})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Hangup()
```

I checked the logs and noticed that the free provider responds with `NOANSWER` if a call is not allowed (Even though it plays a message). What I want is to:

1. Try calling the `${PRIMARY_PROVIDER}` first.
2. If `NOANSWER` is returned by provider (not that the callee did not answer), then call with `${SECONDARY_PROVIDER}`

How can I modify my dial plan to get the desired results?

**EDIT :** The primary provider is **freephoneline.ca**, and I'm using asterisk **v1.8.2.3-2**

Comment: Including the VOIP server you are using and the version number in the body of your question would be helpful in answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[local]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=${OUTGOING_NAME})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${OUTGOING_NUMBER})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(dest=${EXTEN})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@${PRIMARY_PROVIDER},20,); 20 is how much to call,in seconds
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Goto(s-${DIALSTATUS},1)

exten => s-ANSWER,1,Hangup
exten => s-ANSWERED,1,Hangup
exten => s-NOANSWER,1,Goto(dialnext,1)
exten => s-CHANUNAVAIL,1,Goto(dialnext,1)
exten => s-BUSY,1,Busy
exten => s-FAIL,1,Goto(dialnext,1)
exten => s-CONGESTION,1,Goto(dialnext,1)

exten =>dialnext,1,Dial(SIP/1${dest}@${SECONDARY_PROVIDER})
exten =>dialnext,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: This answer is technically correct but you need to detect CHANUNAVAIL.  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+DIALSTATUS

Comment: 2jfalcon user say he need NOANSWER. 2adaptive: please show output of asterisk verbose log.

Comment: @arheops doesn't matter what he needs... it's what he gets back from the VSP.

Comment: I haven't tested `CHANUNAVAIL` yet, but your answer was helpful.

Comment: Yes, @jfalcon was rignt! `CHANUNAVAIL` is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I do this with google voice and trunks. With my setup I had to make a way to limit gv to 1 channel, also setup a rotation so the first gv trunk is not always hammered since it is first. There is a lot more to this but for just displaying failover I thought this was more than enough:

```
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = ""]?15:)


exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,15,Set(goto=$[${PRIORITY} + 15])
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(thetrunk=feliciesmaty)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($[${${thetrunk}}  > 0]?${goto})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=1)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(Motif/feliciesmaty@gmail.com/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=0)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Verbose(0, getting staus ${DIALSTATUS} );
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "SUCCESS"]?hangup:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "FAILED"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "NOANSWER"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CANCEL"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CONGESTION"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "HANGUP"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "UNKNOWN"]?${goto}:)



exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,30,Set(goto=$[${PRIORITY} + 20])
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(thetrunk=bettyrobertson169gmailcom)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($[${${thetrunk}}  > 0]?${goto})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=1)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(Motif/bettyrobertson169gmailcom/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=0)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Verbose(0, getting staus ${DIALSTATUS} );
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "SUCCESS"]?hangup:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "FAILED"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "NOANSWER"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CANCEL"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CONGESTION"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "HANGUP"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "UNKNOWN"]?${goto}:)




exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,50,Set(goto=$[${PRIORITY} + 25])
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(thetrunk=swigartjosephgmailcom)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($[${${thetrunk}}  > 0]?${goto})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=1)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(Motif/swigartjosephgmailcom/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=0)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Verbose(0, getting staus ${DIALSTATUS} );
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "SUCCESS"]?hangup:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "FAILED"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "NOANSWER"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CANCEL"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CONGESTION"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "HANGUP"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "UNKNOWN"]?${goto}:)



exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,75,Set(goto=$[${PRIORITY} + 25])
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(thetrunk=bettyrobertson169gmailcom)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($[${${thetrunk}}  > 0]?${goto})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=1)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(Motif/bettyrobertson169gmailcom/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=0)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Verbose(0, getting staus ${DIALSTATUS} );
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "SUCCESS"]?hangup:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "FAILED"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "NOANSWER"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CANCEL"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CONGESTION"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "HANGUP"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "UNKNOWN"]?${goto}:)



exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,100,Set(goto=$[${PRIORITY} + 25])
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(thetrunk=sandralanago)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($[${${thetrunk}}  > 0]?${goto})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=1)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(Motif/sandralanago@gmail.com/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=0)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Verbose(0, getting staus ${DIALSTATUS} );
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "SUCCESS"]?hangup:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "FAILED"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "NOANSWER"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CANCEL"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CONGESTION"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "HANGUP"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "UNKNOWN"]?${goto}:)



exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,125,Set(goto=$[${PRIORITY} + 25])
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(thetrunk=sofiadugal)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($[${${thetrunk}}  > 0]?${goto})
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=1)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(Motif/sofiadugal@gmail.com/${EXTEN}@voice.google.com,,r)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(GLOBAL(${thetrunk})=0)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,Verbose(0, getting staus ${DIALSTATUS} );
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "SUCCESS"]?hangup:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "FAILED"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "NOANSWER"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CANCEL"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "BUSY"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "CONGESTION"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "HANGUP"]?${goto}:)
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "UNKNOWN"]?${goto}:)
```